# Are number ids lighter than strings?

Tags: javascript, mysql, performance

Are numeric ids lighter than strings? Specifically in JavaScript, I'm transferring a lot of data through sockets and I'd like to optimize my code by using numeric ids as id, I mean, if they are smaller than strings. Also, I would use those same ids as the primary keys in my db mySQL tables. The best part is I don't need to retrieve any ids from my db when I get the data from it since the rows get sorted by ids automatically in my arrays. And the only time I pull anything from the db is when I start the server, then I use variables as everyone should.

Comment: In Javascript, number primitive values take 4 bytes, while strings take at least that size, as the length of a string itself already takes 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, number primitive values take 4 bytes, while strings take at least that size, as the length-indication of a string itself already takes 4 bytes. So, you'll certainly use less memory with numbers.

Comment: On the other hand, the size of the `PRIMARY KEY` (or other index) has a rather small impact on the overall performance.  Fetching a row costs a lot, in comparison.

Comment: Yeah I only fetch stuff from my db when the server starts then I update variables.